# Poisson distribution - Number of Failures

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

The number of machine failures per day in a certain factory has a Poisson Distribution with parameter $\lambda=3$.
At present maintenance facilities can repair 3 machines per day. Failures in excess of 3 are repair by a contractor.

a) On a given day, what is the probability of having machines repaired by the contractor?

I did:

$P(X>3)=1-P(X\le3)$  which is

$1-[P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)]$

Using the Poisson distribution formula $P(X=x)\frac{e^-\lambda.\lambda^x}{x!}$

I got that:

$P(X>3)=1-P(X\le3)$=

$1-0.6423$=0.3577

Can anyone let me know if I am thinking correctly?

b) What is the most probable number of machine failures per day?

I was thinking of doing:

Using the Poisson Distribution table to calculate:

P(X=0)

P(X=1)=P(X<=1) - P(X=0)

P(X=2)=P(X<=2) - P(X=1)

etc. until X=11

Is this correct?

c) Find the expected number of machines repaired in the factory each day, that is those not repaired by the contractor.

I did:

I know that $\mu=E(X)=\lambda$ in this case the expected number is 3 since $\lambda = 3$

d) What is the expected number of machines repaired by the contractor each day?

I am not sure how to do this one. Since in this case $\lambda =3$

Can anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)  The thinking is right. I have not checked the arithmetic.

b) You need to find out which one (?) of $\Pr(X=0)$, $\Pr(X=1)$, $\Pr(X=2)$, $\Pr(X=3)$, $\Pr(X=4)$, and so on is largest. You could calculate (best done without ever touching a calculator). The probabilities are 
$$e^{-3}, \quad e^{-3}\frac{3^1}{1!},\quad e^{-3}\frac{3^2}{2!},\quad e^{-3}\frac{3^3}{3!},\quad e^{-3}\frac{3^4}{4!}, \quad e^{-3}\frac{3^5}{5!},$$
and so on. Note that $\Pr(X=n)$ reaches a maximum at two places, $n=2$ and $n=3$. To get the "$n+1$" term from the "$n$" term, we multiply by $\frac{\lambda}{n+1}$. So probabilities typically increase and then start to decrease. If $\lambda$ is an integer, we get a two way tie for largest probability.

c)  For in-house repairs, the number of failures must be $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$. The expected number of such repairs is $1\cdot\Pr(X=1)+2\cdot\Pr(X=2)+3\cdot\Pr(X=3)$.

d) The **total** expected number of repairs is $3$, by a standard property of the Poisson. So the expected number of contractor repairs is $3$ minus the answer to Question c).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was reading my notes and I thought  that the expected value was the same as the value of $\lambda$ but I did it wrong.

Comment: You are welcome. I did use the fact that the mean of the Poisson is $\lambda$, here $3$, in doing d). For d) uses the fact that the (total) expected value is $3$, from which we subtract the answer to c).